# jQuery :selected not working, always returning same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a very strange problem where the jQuery :selected is always returning the same value.

For the example, lets say I have this HTML:

```
<select class="some_select">
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

then I run this jQuery code on $(document).ready():

```
    $('.some_select').change(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('value'));
    });
```

In the case above, the alert always display the good value of the selected option, but if I run this:

```
var type = $('.some_select :selected').attr('value');
```

with this code, the alert always return '0', no matter what option is selected.

I also tried with:

```
$('.some_select').find(':selected')
```

and

```
$('.some_select').filter(':selected')
```

also

```
$('.some_select option:selected')
```

Thanks In advance for any help!

Comment: isnt the value of the select always going to be the same as the selected value?

Comment: Seems to work okay http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3d6EF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select element doesn't have a `value` attribute, so alerting `$(this).attr('value')` will alert `undefined`, not the "good value" of the selected option, as you claim.

You don't need to use the `:selected` pseudoclass here. Just use the `.val()` method of the select to retrieve its current value:

```
$('.some_select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/qGuxt/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to tldr Explosion Pills comment. The code you are looking for is

```
$('.some_select').change(function() {
   console.log($(":selected").attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need the `.change(function(){..})` so it can update the value when it is changed, the other snippets of code you have do not get updated when the value is changed. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The second snippet is actually used somewhere else in my code to get the value of a select, without using 'change', and it always return the same value.

Comment: That's what I am saying, you need the `change` if you want it to change.